# How to call PDPageRelease API to release pdf?

Tags: vba, ms-word, acrobat

Here is my code.

```
Public Function GetPDFLastTwentyText(ByVal pstrPdfFilename As String) As String
    Dim PDDoc As Object
    Dim CAcroRect As New Acrobat.AcroRect
    Dim PDPage As Acrobat.AcroPDPage
    Dim PDTxtSelect As Acrobat.AcroPDTextSelect
    Dim CArcoPoint As Acrobat.AcroPoint
    Dim iNumWords As Integer
    Dim iMax As Long
    Dim arPdfLines() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    GetPDFLastTwentyText = ""
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    If fso.FileExists(pstrPdfFilename) Then
        Set PDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        PDDoc.Open pstrPdfFilename
        Set PDPage = PDDoc.AcquirePage(PDDoc.GetNumPages() - 1)
        Set CArcoPoint = PDPage.GetSize()
        CAcroRect.Top = CArcoPoint.y
        CAcroRect.Left = 0
        CAcroRect.Right = CArcoPoint.x
        CAcroRect.bottom = 0
        Set PDTxtSelect = PDDoc.CreateTextSelect(PDDoc.GetNumPages() - 1, CAcroRect)
        ...
        PDDoc.Close
    End If

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set PDTxtSelect = Nothing
    Set CAcroRect = Nothing
    Set CArcoPoint = Nothing
    Set PDPage = Nothing
    Set PDDoc = Nothing
    
End Function
```

I have no idea to use this API.

> PDPageRelease()

And Is there official document about this API?

Here is the Description that I find in adobe's API document.

> PDPage PDDocAcquirePage(PDDoc doc, ASInt32 pageNum)
>
> Gets a PDPage from
> a document. It increments the page's reference count. After you are
> done using the page, release it using PDPageRelease(). If
> PDPageRelease() is not called, it could block the document containing
> the page from being closed. To avoid such problems, use the
> CSmartPDPage class, as it ensures that the page is released as it goes
> out of scope.

It mention that It should call this API after you call 『AcquirePage』.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA or other scripting languages you work with OLE Automation. The description you will find "Acrobat Interapplication Communication Reference".
There is no PDPageRelease() element. PDPageRelease() belong to the plugin API. A plugin can only be written in C#.

If you only want to close the document, without closing Acrobat you can use the following code instead of "PDDoc.Close". Br. Reinhard

```
Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App")   '//connect to Form API
exe = "app.execMenuItem('Close');"         '//write js-code to variable
AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript exe     '//execute js-code
```